# Finding linked topics in DBPedia using SPARQL

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

Consider we have these two topics:

http://dbpedia.org/page/Jason_Furman
and
http://dbpedia.org/page/London

For the first topic, Jason Furman, we can see on the property almaMater that he went to:

http://dbpedia.org/page/London_School_of_Economics

And looking at London School of Economics we see that it has London as value of the city property.

So my question is:
If we have two topics, A and B, how can we find property values of A that has topic B in any of it's properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select distinct ?a ?p ?y ?q ?b where {
  values ?a { dbpedia:Jason_Furman }
  values ?b { dbpedia:London }

  ?a ?p ?y .
  ?y ?q ?b .
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20%3Fa%20%3Fp%20%3Fy%20%3Fq%20%3Fb%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20values%20%3Fa%20%7B%20dbpedia%3AJason_Furman%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20values%20%3Fb%20%7B%20dbpedia%3ALondon%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Fa%20%3Fp%20%3Fy%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fy%20%3Fq%20%3Fb%20.%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

(Note that there are two results because there are *two* such properties:  **dbpprop:almaMater** and **dbpedia-owl:almaMater**.)